# Scope of function in ViewModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to call a function from my ViewModel from a click event. It appears that the function goes out of scope the moment I call it from within a foreach loop. New to JavaScript, and trying to wrap my head around how / why has proved futile.

Function:

```
$dyn.controls.Test = function (props, element) {
    var self = this;

    $dyn.ui.Control.apply(this, arguments);
    $dyn.ui.applyDefaults(this, props, $dyn.ui.defaults.Test);

    self.RowItem = [
        {
        .
        .
        .
        }];

    self.Periods = [
        { Label: "13:00", Open: true },
        { Label: "13:10", Open: true },
        .
        .
        .
        { Label: "14:30", Open: true }];

    self.clickedMe = function (action) { //This is the function I want to call
        alert("Clicked");
    };
    .
    .
    .
```

In HTML, this works:

```
<div data-dyn-bind="foreach: $data.RowItem" class="table" id="workspace">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="resourceCell" data-dyn-bind="attr: {id: $data.Id}">
            <div data-dyn-bind="text: $data.Id" class="resourceCell_inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="periodRow" data-dyn-bind="foreach: $parent(0).Periods, click: function(event) {$parent(0).clickedMe(event);}">
            <div class="periodCell"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this does not:

```
<div data-dyn-bind="foreach: $data.RowItem" class="table" id="workspace">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="resourceCell" data-dyn-bind="attr: {id: $data.Id}">
            <div data-dyn-bind="text: $data.Id" class="resourceCell_inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="periodRow" data-dyn-bind="foreach: $parent(0).Periods">
            <div class="periodCell" data-dyn-bind="click: function(event) {$parent(0).clickedMe(event);}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I obviously want my function to be called from the "cell" divs, not the row. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you're in the scope of another `foreach` loop, the `$parent` keyword no longer refers to the object you think it is (`$root`) but to the `Periods` array.

Whenever you  know that the `function` / `property` you're referring to is on the root view-model, you should use `$root` instead:

```
<div class="periodCell"
     data-dyn-bind="click: function(event) { $root.clickedMe(event); }"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this before (And now again) but $root still does not give me access to the function.

Comment: @Weezul-HiGHSoftware Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Yeah, same error: "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'clickedMe' at click (Function code:17:48)"

I must add, I am trying this in Dynamics AX, and am starting to suspect that Microsoft's implementation might be slightly different to what it is supposed to, as I believe your suggestion to be the right answer (Will mark it as such also) However, I get no error on $root, and cannot imagine that they would not use the standard libraries.

Comment: @Weezul-HiGHSoftware Maybe you need to use the same syntax that AX uses for `parent`. Try with `$root(0)` instead. If it still doesn't work, you can also try `$parent(0).$parent` (although not recommended).

Comment: I have tried both of those before, get the error that it is expecting a function the moment I add brackets to $root, or the same message as above when using parent.parent. I also looked through existing code in other places where they use the same with no luck. Thanks for the help anyway, will continue searching through their code :)

Answer (score 1):

First one works because scope is same, but in a loop, every iteration is represented as `$data` and this might not have the property `clickedMe`. You can try using

`$parent.$parent(0).clickedMe(event);`

Here `$parent` will point to the initial scope and from there you can go to its parent using `$parent(0)`.

Also, instead of

```
click: function(event) {$parent(0).clickedMe(event);}
```

you can try

```
click: $parent(0).clickedMe
```

`event` is automatically added as parameter.